# How to achieve code folding / collapsing for a sql without losing the formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sql code where I need to fold / collapse the code at specific sql clauses like SELECT, WHERE, FROM.
On click / hovering of the mouse, the rest of the sql needs to be displayed.

I tried collapsibles and few other features but when I make a specific sql clause as collapsible, I lose the formatting and it gets auto aligned to the left. didn't help.

I am very new to this and hence don't have much idea on how to proceed ahead.
Any help is much appreciated.

HTML collapsibles, bootstrap collapsible, HTML details & summary tags.

```
SELECT /* collapse here*/ column1
    ,column2
FROM /* collapse here*/ table1 
    ,table2 
    ,(
        SELECT /* collapse here*/ column1
        FROM dual
        ) table3
WHERE /* collapse here*/
    table1.col1 = table2.col1
    AND table2.col2 = table3.col1
```

SQL code should have similar features as Javascript code folding, where we can minimize and expand as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this,Here I just took button but instead of it you can use + and - sign.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style>
 .collapsible {
   background-color: #777;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
   outline: none;
   font-size: 15px;
 }

 .active, .collapsible:hover {
   background-color: #555;
 }

 .content {
   padding: 0 18px;
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h2>Collapsibles</h2>

 <p>A Collapsible:</p>
 <button class="collapsible">SELECT</button>
 <div class="content">
   <p>
     column1
  ,column2
 </p></div>

 <button class="collapsible">FROM</button>
 <div class="content">
   <p>
   table1 
  ,table2 
  ,(
   SELECT  column1
   FROM dual
   ) table3
   
 </p></div>

 <button class="collapsible">WHERE</button>
 <div class="content">
   <p> 
  table1.col1 = table2.col1
  AND table2.col2 = table3.col1
   </p>
 </div>


 <script>
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
   coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
   });
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank You. The main problem I have is the alignment. Its by default aligned to the center. I want it to retain the original alignment coming from the sql code.